# Haskell-style type families

Tags: haskell, type-families, idris

In Haskell, I might write a typeclass with a `type` declaration to create a type family, like so:

```
class ListLike k where
    type Elem ::  * -> *
    fromList :: [Elem k] -> k
```

And then write instances like this:

```
instance ListLike [a] where
    type Elem [a] = a
    fromList = id

instance ListLike Bytestring where
    type Elem Bytestring = Char
    fromList = pack
```

I'm aware that you can create typeclasses  and type-level functions in Idris, but the methods operate on data of the given type, not the type itself.

How can I make a typeclass-constrained type family in Idris like the one above?

Comment: I think you don't need this - remember you have even better tools: [first class types](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/typesfuns.html#first-class-types) - so you can write `Elem` as a function

Comment: @Carsten I realise that, but how might I constrain that function to instances of that typeclass?

Comment: I think you probably don't have a problem with associated type families at all. Idris does not, however, offer associated *data* families, and I don't know if that will keep you from doing something or other. It also doesn't have Haskell-style non-associated type families; there is no pattern matching whatsoever on type constructors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no clue if you will ever find a use for this, but I think the obvious translation should be

```
class ListLike k where
    llElem : Type
    fromList : List llElem -> k

instance ListLike (List a) where
    llElem = a
    fromList = id

instance ListLike (Maybe a) where
  llElem = a
  fromList [] = Nothing
  fromList (a::_) = Just a
```

#### usage

```
λΠ> the (Maybe Int) (fromList [3])
Just 3 : Maybe Int
λΠ> the (List Int) (fromList [3])
[3] : List Int
```

Comment: I might ask, why isn't `llElem : Type -> Type` rather than `Type`? Surely it's an undecidable instance?

Comment: load it into idris and have a look at the types (`:t`) - you can get almost the same in Haskell with `data` instead of `type` inside your family - `llElem` is `ListLike k => Type` so it makes sense in `ListLike k => List llElem -> k` and you don't really need/want more here (or so I guess)

Comment: another way to do it in Haskell would be with a two param type class and [functional dependencies](https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies) - the important fact is that `k`implies `llElem`

Comment: @AJFarmar `llElem` can't be used on its own, but the appropriate instance can be determined from the use of `fromList`. Idris doesn't actually check this at the moment in the definition of this class (but it should and will soon).

Comment: For me Idris 0.9.18 reports 3 errors for the given code
`DecEq.idr:1:7:When elaborating type of Main.fromList:
Can't resolve type class ListLike k
DecEq.idr:5:10:ListLike is not a type class
DecEq.idr:9:10:ListLike is not a type class`